# Server 2016 - Storage Pool and Extending a virtual disk

Tags: windows, storage, windows-server-2016

I have a storage pool on Windows Server 2016 and the underlying virtual disk is running out of space. I installed a new drive and added it to the storage pool and the pool now has a free space of 8.25TB. When I try to extend the virtual disk it shows there is no space available. The current virtual disk is 23.6 TB with a layout of parity and a provisioning as fixed. The virtual disk and pool both have healthy statuses. As a test,

The pool consists of 6x 8TB drives. Seems like something obvious is missing but I can't figure out why I can't extend the virtual disk. Anyone run into this before?

I tried adding a new virtual disk to the current pool but it only shows a capacity available of 6GB so it doesn't show any of the free capacity in the pool. I have tried rebooting